# can't connect to my Asterisk server with jssip library, Wrong Password error

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, freepbx, jssip

i can connect to my freePbx server with jssip.
but registeration got faild with wrong password in Asterisk Logs.
i can connect and register with none WebRtc and WebSocket clients with same password for my PjSip Extension.

it's work in .net library Ozeki with the same user, pass and etc but in nodejs and webRtc it's not working.

the Asterisk Log:

```
ERROR[24788]: res_http_websocket.c:506 ws_safe_read: Error readng from webScoket: Connection rest by peer.
NOTICE[33279]: chan_sip.c28486 handle_request_register: Registeration from '<sip:170@192.168.0.210>' faild for 192.168.0.250:43751 - wrong password
```

jssip conf:

```
var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('ws://192.168.0.210:8089/ws');

var configuration = {
    sockets           : [ socket ],
    authorization_user: '170',
    uri               : 'sip:170@192.168.0.210',
    ws_servers        : 'ws://192.168.0.210:8089/ws',
    password          : '856589',
    realm             : '192.168.0.210',
    display_name      : '170',
    contact_uri       : 'sip:170@192.168.0.210'
};
```

jssip log:

```
olden@golden-client:~/LocalFiles/projects/jssip$ node ./index.js  JsSIP version 3.0.21 +0ms  jssip-node-websocket new() [url:"ws://192.168.0.210:8088/ws", options:undefined] +0ms
  JsSIP:UA new() [configuration:{ sockets: [ NodeWebSocket { _url: 'ws://192.168.0.210:8088/ws', _options: {}, _sipUri: 'sip:192.168.0.210:8088;transport=ws', _viaTransport: 'WS', _ws: null } ], authorization_user: '170', uri: 'sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060', ws_servers: 'ws://192.168.0.210:8088/ws', password: '170170', realm: '192.168.0.210', display_name: '170', contact_uri: 'sip...@192.168.0.210' }] +0ms
  JsSIP:Transport new() +0ms
  JsSIP:UA configuration parameters after validation: +15ms
  JsSIP:UA - authorization_user: "170" +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - password: NOT SHOWN +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - realm: "192.168.0.210" +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - ha1: NOT SHOWN +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - display_name: "170" +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - uri: sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060 +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - contact_uri: {"_parameters":{},"_headers":{},"_scheme":"sip","_user":"170","_host":"192.168.0.210"} +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - instance_id: "f3a58a94-b426-4a8d-8b15-9f7208a42f9b" +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - use_preloaded_route: false +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - session_timers: true +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - no_answer_timeout: 60000 +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - register: true +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - register_expires: 600 +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - registrar_server: sip:192.168.0.210:5060 +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - connection_recovery_max_interval: null +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - connection_recovery_min_interval: null +0ms
  JsSIP:UA - via_host: "192.168.0.210" +0ms
  JsSIP:UA start() +0ms
  JsSIP:Transport connect() +1ms
connecting
  jssip-node-websocket connect() +18ms
  jssip-node-websocket WebSocket connecting [url:"ws://192.168.0.210:8088/ws"] +0ms
  jssip-node-websocket WebSocket open [url:"ws://192.168.0.210:8088/ws"] +18ms
connected
  JsSIP:Transport send() +22ms
  JsSIP:Transport sending message:
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport REGISTER sip:192.168.0.210:5060 SIP/2.0
  JsSIP:Transport Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.0.210;branch=z9hG4bK160956
  JsSIP:Transport Max-Forwards: 69
  JsSIP:Transport To: <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>
  JsSIP:Transport From: "170" <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=s9bkng5emf
  JsSIP:Transport Call-ID: 6ra4f68tegdmqllfoa7kja
  JsSIP:Transport CSeq: 1 REGISTER
  JsSIP:Transport Contact: <sip...@192.168.0.210>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:f3a58a94-b426-4a8d-8b15-9f7208a42f9b>";expires=600
  JsSIP:Transport Expires: 600
  JsSIP:Transport Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
  JsSIP:Transport Supported: path,gruu,outbound
  JsSIP:Transport User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.21
  JsSIP:Transport Content-Length: 0
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport  +0ms
  jssip-node-websocket send() +3ms
  jssip-node-websocket WebSocket message received +3ms
  JsSIP:Transport received text message:
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
  JsSIP:Transport Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.0.210;branch=z9hG4bK160956;received=192.168.0.3;rport=35832
  JsSIP:Transport From: "170" <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=s9bkng5emf
  JsSIP:Transport To: <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=as0f727a9b
  JsSIP:Transport Call-ID: 6ra4f68tegdmqllfoa7kja
  JsSIP:Transport CSeq: 1 REGISTER
  JsSIP:Transport Server: FPBX-13.0.192.19(13.12.1)
  JsSIP:Transport Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
  JsSIP:Transport Supported: replaces, timer
  JsSIP:Transport WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="078cc3e4"
  JsSIP:Transport Content-Length: 0
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport  +3ms
  JsSIP:DigestAuthentication authenticate() | response generated +0ms
  JsSIP:Transport send() +10ms
  JsSIP:Transport sending message:
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport REGISTER sip:192.168.0.210:5060 SIP/2.0
  JsSIP:Transport Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.0.210;branch=z9hG4bK4224730
  JsSIP:Transport Max-Forwards: 69
  JsSIP:Transport To: <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>
  JsSIP:Transport From: "170" <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=s9bkng5emf
  JsSIP:Transport Call-ID: 6ra4f68tegdmqllfoa7kja
  JsSIP:Transport CSeq: 2 REGISTER
  JsSIP:Transport Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="170", realm="asterisk", nonce="078cc3e4", uri="sip:192.168.0.210:5060", response="26576b92bf68c3d315d480b02d53783c"
  JsSIP:Transport Contact: <sip...@192.168.0.210>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:f3a58a94-b426-4a8d-8b15-9f7208a42f9b>";expires=600
  JsSIP:Transport Expires: 600
  JsSIP:Transport Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
  JsSIP:Transport Supported: path,gruu,outbound
  JsSIP:Transport User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.21
  JsSIP:Transport Content-Length: 0
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport  +0ms
  jssip-node-websocket send() +11ms
  jssip-node-websocket WebSocket message received +1ms
  JsSIP:Transport received text message:
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
  JsSIP:Transport Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.0.210;branch=z9hG4bK4224730;received=192.168.0.3;rport=35832
  JsSIP:Transport From: "170" <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=s9bkng5emf
  JsSIP:Transport To: <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=as0f727a9b
  JsSIP:Transport Call-ID: 6ra4f68tegdmqllfoa7kja
  JsSIP:Transport CSeq: 2 REGISTER
  JsSIP:Transport Server: FPBX-13.0.192.19(13.12.1)
  JsSIP:Transport Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
  JsSIP:Transport Supported: replaces, timer
  JsSIP:Transport Content-Length: 0
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport
  JsSIP:Transport  +3ms

{ response:
   IncomingResponse {
     data: 'SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.0.210;branch=z9hG4bK4224730;received=192.168.0.3;rport=35832\r\nFrom: "170" <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=s9bkng5emf\r\nTo: <sip:170@192.168.0.210:5060>;tag=as0f727a9b\r\nCall-ID: 6ra4f68tegdmqllfoa7kja\r\nCSeq: 2 REGISTER\r\nServer: FPBX-13.0.192.19(13.12.1)\r\nAllow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE\r\nSupported:replaces, timer\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n',
     headers:
      { Via: [Array],
        From: [Array],
        To: [Array],
        'Call-ID': [Array],
        CSeq: [Array],
        Server: [Array],
        Allow: [Array],
        Supported: [Array],
        'Content-Length': [Array] },
     method: 'REGISTER',
     via:
      { protocol: 'SIP',
        transport: 'WS',
        host_type: 'IPv4',
        host: '192.168.0.210',
        branch: 'z9hG4bK4224730',
        received: '192.168.0.3' },
     via_branch: 'z9hG4bK4224730',
     call_id: '6ra4f68tegdmqllfoa7kja',
     cseq: 2,
     from: NameAddrHeader { _uri: [Object], _parameters: [Object], _display_name: '170' },
     from_tag: 's9bkng5emf',
     to:
      NameAddrHeader {
        _uri: [Object],
        _parameters: [Object],
        _display_name: undefined },
     to_tag: 'as0f727a9b',
     body: '',
     sdp: null,
     status_code: 403,
     reason_phrase: 'Forbidden' },
  cause: 'Rejected' }
```

Comment: Debug is offtopic. Too much factors - different encryption, nat traversing etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

The REGISTRATION process follows, as would be expected, the procedure specified in [RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261), that's to say, a first REGISTER is answered by a 401 error response that causes a second REGISTER with authorization information. In this case, the server rejects those data.

```
170 (REGISTER) ---------------------> Asterisk
170 <----------(401 - Not authorized) Asterisk
170 (REGISTER with Auth info) ------> Asterisk
170 <----------------(407 - Rejected) Asterisk
```

So, asterisk is rejecting the register because it does not like the second REGISTER message.

```
Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="170", realm="asterisk", nonce="078cc3e4", uri="sip:192.168.0.210:5060", response="26576b92bf68c3d315d480b02d53783c"
```

Well, realm "asterisk" is not the same configured in jssip, and it does not follow what it is specified in the RFC:

> Operators of user agents or proxy servers that will authenticate received requests MUST adhere to the following guidelines for creation of a realm string for their server:
>
> - Realm strings MUST be globally unique.  It is RECOMMENDED that a realm string contain a hostname or domain name, following the recommendation in Section 3.2.1 of RFC 2617 [17].
> - Realm strings SHOULD present a human-readable identifier that can be rendered to a user.

So, you should configure sip.conf to define the realm string in asterisk to follow the above rules. Anyway, note that even if jssip was configured with a different "realm", in the second REGISTER it is used the field coming in the first response. So, I do not think it is the problem.

Other thing is uri="sip:192.168.0.210:5060" in the second REGISTER that does not include the user name. If it followed the next example, taken from the  "sip:170:192.168.0.210:5060"

```
Authorization: Digest username="bob",..., uri="sip:bob@biloxi.com",..."
```

It is not clear to me why uri does not contain the username as it is specified in jssip.conf. I would remove "authorization_user" from the configuration, as it is an optional parameter and test.

Answer (score 2):

Disable chan_sip (Settings > Advanced Settings - Dialplan and Operational - SIP Channel Driver=pjsip). And then it worked!